# Type as an overridable class attribute

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'd like to create a pretty generic class for inheritance, but I'm having issues.

As of right now, I have two service classes (called Service_A and Service_B) that serve the same purpose, except *Service_A* works with *Class_A*, and *Service_B* with *Class_B*. Those classes are so similar that for now, only the mention of the types (Class_A and Class_B) vary between them.

What I'd like to do is have the code written once, in a more generic class (EntityService), from which Service_A and Service_B would inherit.

However, I haven't managed to find a way to have the methods of Entityuse a "generic" class/type that Service_A and Service_B would override, so that all of the code would be transferable without having to override all the methods or specify the type on each method call.

For example, this is what EntityService looks like:

```js
declare class Observable<T> { x: T }

declare class Actor {
    doStuff<T>(anything: T): T[];
    getData<I>(): I;
    getObservable<U, I>(data: I): Observable<U[]>;
}

interface Entity {
    param_1: number,
    param_2: number,
}

class EntityObj {
    id: string;
    param_1: number;
    param_2: number;

    constructor(id: string, param_1: number, param_2: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.param_1 = param_1;
        this.param_2 = param_2;
    }

    static fromInterface(entity: Entity, id: string): EntityObj {
            return new this(id, entity.param_1, entity.param_2);
    }
}

export class EntityService {

    /* What I'd like to be able to use:
     * static classTypeAlias: EntityObj;
     * static interfaceTypeAlias: Entity;
     */

    constructor(private readonly actor: Actor) { }

    getEntityObjs(): Observable<EntityObj[]> | null {
        let data: Entity = this.actor.getData()
        let entityObjs: Observable<EntityObj[]> = this.actor.getObservable<EntityObj, Entity>(data);
        return entityObjs;
    }

    getObjFromInterface(): EntityObj {
        let entityObj: EntityObj = EntityObj.fromInterface(this.actor.getData(), "foo");
        return entityObj;
    }

    update(entity: EntityObj): void { let entityDoc = this.actor.doStuff<Entity>(entity); }
}
```

And have Service_A be able to call methods like update() with its parameter implicitly being of type "Class_A" or getEntityObjs(), and it implicitly returning something of type "Observable<Class_A[]> | null"

I tried looking at generic types, but couldn't manage to use them either without extending them from EntityObj when trying to access properties, or use the value of generic types associated to the class (like `class EntityService<classType, interfaceType> {...}`) to specify the type of args / returns.

Any pointers towards any kind of solution / proper technique would be very welcome

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that isn't pseudocode (like `...` and undeclared types and values) so that it's easier for others to get to work on the issue and have something concrete against which to test potential solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit is neither reproducible (as it depends on private types like `Entity` and `EntityObj`) nor minimal (as it apparently depends on third party frameworks like angular, firestore, and rxjs, none of which are really relevant to what you're asking about.)  Could you please try to provide a [mre] that others can paste into their own IDEs that clearly shows your issue and immediately allows others to start working on it?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I was in the middle of doing just that, it should be better now.

Comment: And the part about being minimal? Unless your question is *about* third party frameworks, your code shouldn’t depend on them.  Have you read the description of what a [mre] is? If not, I’ve linked it twice, uh, three times.

Comment: I'm trying to reduce it, thanks for your patience and pieces of advice. It's a bit of a mess and I'm a bit lost too

Comment: This is getting closer but [unused generic type parameters](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) act strangely and are therefore not good examples; you could add some use [as shown here maybe](//tsplay.dev/NdvaYW)  Note that I had to fix an issue with `EntityObj` vs `EntityObj[]` which shows up as soon as you fix the unused type parameter.  Anyway, *maybe* you're looking for something like [this](//tsplay.dev/N73zoN), but I'm not sure what purpose `Entity` (or `I`) is serving; [why do we need it at all](//tsplay.dev/NrQ3Dw)?

Comment: The code should be clearer about the use of Entity now.
I think the last piece of code you're giving answers my question. If I manage to make it work, and nobody has done so before then, I'll answer the post myself. Thank you!

Comment: So then [does this version meet your needs](https://tsplay.dev/mMzOzW)?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Or maybe [something like this instead](https://tsplay.dev/w6pzGm)?  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: I've been trying to understand everything [about the one you posted 9mins ago](https://tsplay.dev/mMzOzW). It looks like it demonstrates everything I need.
I fail to understand why `C extends I` at line 30 however. Is it necessary?
[The second one](https://tsplay.dev/w6pzGm) however has me completely lost honestly.
There is one thing I forgot to ask, that is about accessing properties of a generic like so `get_attr<T>(entity: T): number { return entity.param_1 }`, how would you do it? (this method has been added to the code example of the main post)

Comment: • Whether that's necessary or not depends on you, not me.  Your example has `EntityObj` being assignable to `Entity`, and they're named similarly, so I imagined it was important.  If not, then remove it.  • Expanding the scope of the question as a followup to someone helping you isn't ideal. I'd have to ask you questions about what you intend (e.g., you want `return entity.param_1` to somehow work for every possible subclass? Maybe you just want some kind of abstract method that needs to be implemented, but then need to figure out the return type) and this isn't the right place for that.

Comment: I'd suggest if you have followup questions you post them after you get this one answered. If you want me to write up either [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mMzOzW) or [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w8X6Vw) as an answer (modulo the `C extends I` which is up to you) then let me know and I'll do it when I get a chance. Otherwise I'll disengage. Good luck!

Comment: Okay, I hadn't realized one could navigate from an interface to and object like that.
I believe the first version better suits my needs, without the need of the `C extends I`.  Thanks for everything!

Comment: Like [this version then](https://tsplay.dev/NllMXN)?  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (but need to take a break first)

Comment: Yes, this one answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward approach if you want to be able to parameterize subclasses of `EntityService` so that they have different types for what you're calling the `classTypeAlias` and the `interfaceTypeAlias` would be to make `EntityClass` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in type parameters corresponding to these types; let's call them `C` and `I` respectively:

```
export class EntityService<C, I> {
  ⋯
}
```

So the first thing to do would be to replace every instance of `EntityObj` with `C` and `Entity` with `I` inside `EntityService`:

```
export class EntityService<C, I> {

  constructor(private readonly actor: Actor) { }

  getEntityObjs(): Observable<C[]> | null {
    let data: I = this.actor.getData()
    let entityObjs: Observable<C[]> = this.actor.getObservable<C, I>(data);
    return entityObjs;
  }

  getObjFromInterface(): C {
    let entityObj: C = C.fromInterface(this.actor.getData(), "foo"); // error
    // --------------> ~
    // 'C' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
    return entityObj;
  }

  update(entity: C): void {
    let entityDoc = this.actor.doStuff<I>(entity); // error
    // ---------------------------------> ~~~~~~
    // Argument of type 'C' is not assignable to parameter of type 'I'.
  }

}
```

That mostly works except for two errors.

The bottom error happens because we call `doStuff<I>(entity)` but pass an `entity` of type `C` instead of `I`.  This could be fixed by [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `C` to extend `I`, but if you don't want to do that we can just change it so that we call `doStuff<C>(entity)` instead:

```
update(entity: C): void {
  let entityDoc = this.actor.doStuff<C>(entity); // okay
}
```

The top error happens because we have replaced `EntityObj` the *class constructor* with `C` which is just a *type*.  Oops, that means `EntityService` needs to access a class constructor value of the appropriate type.  Since the code uses a `fromInterface(data, str)` where `data` is of type `I` and it returns a value of type `C`, then we need to access a value of type `{fromInterface(data: I, str: string): C}`.  How can we get it?  Well, one reasonable place is that instances of `EntityService` need to be passed such an object when you construct them.  That leads us to this version:

```
export class EntityService<C, I> {

  constructor(
    private readonly actor: Actor,
    public ctor: { fromInterface(e: I, id: string): C } // <-- add it
  ) { }

  getEntityObjs(): Observable<C[]> | null {
    let data: I = this.actor.getData<I>()
    let entityObjs: Observable<C[]> = this.actor.getObservable<C, I>(data);
    return entityObjs;
  }

  getObjFromInterface(): C {
    let entityObj: C = this.ctor.fromInterface(this.actor.getData(), "foo");
    // --------------> ^^^^^^^^^ <--- use it
    return entityObj;
  }

  update(entity: C): void { let entityDoc = this.actor.doStuff<C>(entity); }
}
```

That compiles now.  So how do we use it?

---

Well, we can subclass it with specific `C` and `I` type arguments and also pass the `ctor` within the subclass constructor. Like this:

```
class MainEntityService extends EntityService<EntityObj, Entity> {
  constructor(actor: Actor) {
    super(actor, EntityObj);
  }
}
```

So `C` has been specified as `EntityObj`, and `I` has been specified as `Entity`, and the `ctor` object is just the `EntityObj` constructor.
And we can use it:

```
new MainEntityService(new Actor()).getEntityObjs()
// Observable<EntityObj[]> | null
```

Looks good.  In case it matters, here is a different subclass:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
class Bar implements Foo {
  a = "abc";
  b = 123;
  c = "‍♂️";
  static fromInterface(entity: Foo, id: string): Bar {
    return new this();
  }
}

class SomeOtherThing extends EntityService<Bar, Foo> {
  constructor(actor: Actor) { super(actor, Bar) }
}
new SomeOtherThing(new Actor()).getEntityObjs()
// Observable<Bar[]> | null
```

Also looks good.

---

There are undoubtedly other ways to approach this, such that either subclasses don't need to explicitly specify `C` and `I`, or so that `EntityService` is a class factory function where you just write `class MainEntityService extends EntityService(EntityObj) {}`, etc., but this way works so I won't digress to include every possible approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwPICNkhgNykwhAB4AVAPngG94APALnjPgF8Aod0JORaVeAEEwAFwD2MGu3jxgYgMoiArgDMV5CgAooAOwCeIgBYBLHQHMmZAJSWA2gF0A3NPhmQIgCJQRUEgEktG3g-Zxk3ESwcfEJiEgBVABpgrWBvKCY-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-IwJU1StkwcZDiu7ivmaWzgSScaolyPJ8uUwGCpoR5-Ce85pK2SQAEQqGIYgEQ68AAPQUWuMDcjAD5UfAAC0LGsWxbFUAAfgx1EAORxrx8CfKWj4qLgaDiPAUBUnorQgEkmBKKGKLwCMJzwEoODAFJaDSQQEBKAghi4CAqKaNMABsACcADMVgPhqz7auuSqbJ+bz1korRjkKLnivAcZBHgYgYqq9bDtBfkeGIHKHgS07YaiciKKo6gBMKb7kYxuB0TxzHsQVhVFQVXGcWVZV5YIMBmEMppCSoMlyfA-GCSpOhiKG4bGGYrp5FSYikm6aH1Y1CC8X4vGoimdYlM6rqdO6noIN60zJjIgbBjAoYrBGb7RvgsZ7omVD+uFHxfEcGb-Dmxh5gghbFiJx6VthNZsB534iE2yotm2UQXl29hUH2gwDpB8CrreE5xSiCWZqenh4fZ4VQaGfmbhg7Y7peB4GrDx4I+enZHdet73ijj6as5b4ftNH0NhEf4AahAqgUEEFhSjq7o8q8HYohyGAWhIFClh8O4YuViEcRpFZdROUSHlxXsVxeUtUJJbNHAYkwBJA3SU0ckKUpuxoGp5gaVpOlSfA+mGfAxlwGZlm2cjKOOS+PNuXTKZeT5GVmuBQUhdpnPhdzb7RbFeNogTyXKGoe5aH5ctCQA1lAeg+zIs2cOwG0hmGqx7TG1Qk0mp2phdPzYZoKY3Xdj5FsJZbYS9mZjOFrRKEQ7KIBWNCcszQEi8KGTSvssrAuY7PvTIb11uE32bL9W5YwDe7diDShg2HEPQVDwSTvFBMS746Vu6jMEbj9a--cT+5A8f+OJeERO7le6Vk5SHvU7BP2OhcG-JmKER4YVnnvCO-9Nh8xjqiRKgsWboVAmLWcZ98LwCIiRMiP8nyexpsqQBMg-beF8m+IOTBgqhX3mjSOMVn6x0SvHVKScA5inIhwZ0O14AAFkoCmEjPtPAsY1x0HKDoYAu0zRCMOsvJIkYTouHOumWuz0hCvSHMgLyuBtDYXkQQzY5N3olB0HqXh-CdCCNLkKUx+oqz-CsFYBGy9frsEYu-WIy8t79ggJwMorMEC-hIjsdIU9jjmDOJgOErwODcIAEKwF2J0VoxAFr1DQEEganNpLYgIoQMABFIkkl6NMGyZxo4EUAHwbgB2XcALAEgAhMkAPB-hSXCsgaByRBYDQJ+SYJkieQJwlmCCAkyQe9f46n1NSVsjplj8DQPIHkIB0BGFwGQEwFtAziMkfAKxB0y4jKSJkxR7w0yXVUW3dR1ZB5aLklmY8SQRkIk4S6MxCyFrLMdmsk4mhbGXIcU4peBjXHuPXsTEZ3jQa+KAA)